# Android Scale image from Gallery Based on Image Size

Tags: android, image-processing

I have an processing image from Gallery in phone. i used the below code to crop and scale image to a specific size since i had to process very large scale images.
The code worked fine for scaling and cropping, But unfortunately it resized the smaller image(120*120) to (1024*768).

Is there any specific way to avoid scaling to smaller images?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 1024);   
intent.putExtra("outputY", 768);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", return_data);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection",!faceDetection); 
startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_PICKED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to check the size of the image first. Then pass it through the crop activity.

So basically, if image is less or equal to 120x120, or whatever you decide, then don't resize it.